# Testing For Data Shared To All Views To Ensure It Exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.7

I share a few things to all views in my laravel project in AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
    {

        $userLocation = geoip()->getLocation(geoip()->getClientIP());

        view()->share(['user' => \Auth::user(), 'userLocation' => $userLocation]);
    }
```

But when I test against this, they don't show up:

```
/** @test */
public function page_has_recent_reviews()
{
    $response = $this->get(route('home'));

    $response->assertSuccessful();

    $response->assertViewHasAll(['recentReviews', 'recentPhotos']);

    $data = $response->getOriginalContent()->getData();

    print_r(array_keys($data)); exit;

}
```

The dumped content contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => recentReviews
    [1] => recentPhotos
)
```

But none of the data shared to the view.  How does one test this?

Comment: If you do `$response->getOriginal('user')`, what do you get?

Comment: "BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Http\Response::getOriginal does not exist."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time, I found that if you share the data in a [composer callback](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers) in the AppServiceProvider (boot method), it will then render in tests:

```
view()->composer('*', function($view) use ($userLocation, $ratingStars, $icons)
    {
        $view->with(['userLocation' => $userLocation, 'user' => \Auth::user());
    });
```